# Xcode 4.0.2/4A2002a: Editor > Code Folding -> Focus follows selection: Grey/Disabled. Why?

Tags: ide, xcode4, focus, folding

I'd love to use the feature
"Editor > Code Folding > Focus follows selection"
but unfortunately it's greyed out/disabled.

Any idea how to turn it on?

Comment: Okay. I just found the solution (more like a hack, the GUI option in Xcode seems to be broken) myself.

 - Quit Xcode4
 - Add a new boolean key "DVTTextCodeFocusFollowsSelection" to ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist and set it to "true"
 - save & relaunch Xcode

Open the file with the Propertylist Editor, not Xcode - otherwise Xcode will overwrite your changes. Sorry for the ugly formatting. Due to Stackoverflows restrictions I cant answer my own question for another 8 hours and the mini-Markdown in the comments completely sucks.

Answer (score 2):

To take your answer from the comment, here it is in a nice command line form.  Just paste this command in the Terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode DVTTextCodeFocusFollowsSelection -bool TRUE
```